# KendoUI: Unable to bind data to HTML elements from JSON file.

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I am new to kendo ui and mvvm, and I'm facing this issue:

I'm having a JSON file in the follow format:

```
[
{
"Id":1,
"img":"shoes.png"},
{"Id":2,
"img":"books.png"}
    }
]
```

I am reading the file using the sample mentioned online by kendo guys as follows:

```
var crudServiceBaseUrl = "pro.json";
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            productsSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: crudServiceBaseUrl,
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return {
                                models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                            };
                        }
                        return options;
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "Id"
                    }
                }
            })
        });

        kendo.bind($("#form-container"), viewModel);
```

I am able to bind the data from the data source to a Kendo Control such as a dropdownlist or some other Kendo Control. But when I try binding the data to an HTML Control (mostly an img tag). It stops working and gives an error saying "this.parent" is not a function.

following is the HTML which works:

```
Select Product: <select data-role="dropdownlist" data-value-field="Id" data-text-field="img"
                         data-bind="source: productsSource"></select>
```

However binding to a normal `<img>` tag does not work. In short I need to bind images based on src value to a div using kendo ui mvvm.

Kindly help me out. Thanks!!

-
Hardik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Kendo MVVM cannot bind a data source to an HTML element. Only Kendo UI widgets can be bound to a `kendo.data.DataSource`. Using a widget e.g. the ListView would work for a `DIV`:

```
<div data-role="listview" 
     data-template="template"
     data-bind="source: productsSource">
</div>

<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <img data-bind="attr: { src: img }" />
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Atanas,I dont want to bind it to a Select element. All I want is to bind <img> elements to an empty div. The Src of the images is coming from the JSON file.

Comment: Fine. no problem :) Thanks for all the help... I have also created a sample project in JSbin.. But that is not in MVVM format... If you could convert that code to MVVM..that would also be helpful.. [link](http://jsbin.com/ovupam/5/edit)..however I am having the JSON file at my end...

Comment: Yes... That's right... using any of the Kendo Widgets like a listview or a dropdownlist works well... But apart from the Kendo widgets, any HTML control does not work... Thanks again for the response!! :)